# Insert handles for bootstrap carousel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have tried to make a carousel to display text testimonials with bootstrap. I have included the snippet here. I included the handles but they were not working so I removed it. Please do let me know what the problem is. I included code given in the example. It works in the example but not when I insert the same code in my page.

[codepen](http://codepen.io/matthewhirsch/pen/OPwQRL)

```css
.carousel-content {
  color: white;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 5%;
}
#text-carousel {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #0489B1;
}
#testimonials {
  background-color: #0489B1;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="testimonials" id="testimonials">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row text-center mt mb">
      <h1>- Testimonials -</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="text-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="row mt mb">
        <div class="col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-6">
          <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
              <div class="carousel-content">
                <div>
                  <p>
                    <i class="fa fa-quote-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    Sapiente, ducimus, voluptas, mollitia voluptatibus nemo explicabo sit blanditiis laborum dolore illum fuga veniam quae expedita libero accusamus quas harum ex numquam necessitatibus provident deleniti tenetur iusto officiis recusandae corporis culpa quaerat?
                    <i class="fa fa-quote-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <div class="carousel-content">
                <div>
                  <p>
                    <i class="fa fa-quote-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi, sint fuga temporibus nam saepe delectus expedita vitae magnam necessitatibus dolores tempore consequatur dicta cumque repellendus eligendi ducimus placeat!
                    <i class="fa fa-quote-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <div class="carousel-content">
                <div>
                  <p>
                    <i class="fa fa-quote-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    Sapiente, ducimus, voluptas, mollitia voluptatibus nemo explicabo sit blanditiis laborum dolore illum fuga veniam quae expedita libero accusamus quas harum ex numquam necessitatibus provident deleniti tenetur iusto officiis recusandae corporis culpa quaerat?
                    <i class="fa fa-quote-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dg1wtvxr/ & http://codepen.io/matthewhirsch/pen/OPwQRL

Comment: Are you including the libraries either through hosting on your site or using the CDN links?

Comment: I used CDN links.

Answer (score 0):

Initializes the carousel with an optional options object and starts cycling through items.

```
$('#text-carousel').carousel({
  interval: 2000
});
```

Events:

`slide.bs.carousel` This event fires immediately when the slide instance method is invoked.

```
$('#text-carousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function () {
  console.log('SLIDE INVOKED')
})
```

`slid.bs.carousel` This event is fired when the carousel has completed its slide transition.

```
$('#text-carousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {
  console.log('dededed12112')
})
```

If you are using v4, try with 3.7:

https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js

[Documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel-events)

Comment: I don't know if you misunderstood my question or if I misunderstood your answer. Text is sliding just fine, it is just the handles that are not respobsive on click.

Comment: @Lee The code in your question looks different than the example in codepen. Also, slider controls are missing.
 Make sure that you are loading the libraries in the correct order (load jquery before bootstrap), use "#text-carousel" (Carousel id) for href attributes on slider controls and check the carousel structure. If it doesn't work you could try using JS:  `$('.left.carousel-control').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  $('#text-carousel').carousel('prev');
});`